# What's the German term for "to control for"?

Tags: english-to-german

#### Example sentence

How would you translate:

> In order to control for any retirement related impact, ...

#### Term

The term *to control for* is used in statistics:

- Wikipedia: [controlling for a variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlling_for_a_variable)

#### What I've found so far

The discussion [forum at dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=275100) suggests:

- [bereinigen](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=275100#followup4)
- [kontrollieren](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=275100#followup5)

The PONS dictionary suggests:

- [etwas berücksichtigen](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/englisch-deutsch/control+for) [o. in Betracht ziehen]

Comment: So, if it was me, I would take the English then translate the concept into German-I would take the tack of 'anticipate' for 'to control for' or even 'predict response' but start with German for *anticipate*. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of statistics it should be *kontrollieren/Kontrolle* ([Drittvariablenkontrolle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drittvariablenkontrolle)).

Example:

> Zur Kontrolle von ruhestandsbezogenen Einflüssen ...

In the context of economics you often find *bereinigt um/Bereinigung um*, but then you don't speak of *control for* in English either.

Example:

> inflationsbereinigt, Bereinigung um saisonale Effekte

Comment: You would really say that in the context of statistics? To me, it sounds completely odd (and I've studied math, though I didn't specialize in statistics). Note that the usage in the linguee examples is from fincance (where "Bereinigung" is common), not from statistics .

Comment: @dirkt No you wouldn't. I just had a talk with someone who knows this better, I changed my answer almost entirely to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are asking about the statistical notion of  *controlling for a variable*. It doesn't seem to describe a single technique but a number of different ones that all have the common purpose of finding the effect of a single variable (or maybe sometimes several) in the presence of other, confounding variables. In German one usually makes the specific technique used more explicit: vermeiden (avoid), berücksichtigen (consider), herausrechnen (eliminate (computationally)).

If you really want to (or have to) stay general, you can work with a literal translation of *controlling a confounding variable*: **einen Störfaktor kontrollieren**.

Answer (score 3):

I would translate

> Um den Einfluss des Eintretens in den Ruhestand als Störfaktor zu verringern, ...

I don't know a direct translation. In principle, *bereinigen*, *kontrollieren* and *etwas berücksichtigen* can be valid translations of "to control for", but not in the particular context of the example.

I think this is one of those cases where you have to use expressions appropriate for the particular situation, instead of trying to translate something directly.

The Wikipedia article for [Störfaktor](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B6rfaktor) contains some relevant expressions and terminology.